# Update parent props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Guys I have a modal in which I send array via props and set his state to be equal to this array.Then I'm adding element and its state is updating but its not updating the props...Can someone tell me what should I do in order to update his props ??

```
var FormattedDate = ReactIntl.FormattedDate;
var DiaryTable = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            items : this.props.item,
            globalChecked: false,
            startDate:new Date(),
            endDate:new Date(),
            hours:0
        };
    },
    handleChecked : function (i) {
        // console.log( this.state.items[i].selected);
        this.state.items[i].selected =  !this.state.items[i].selected;
        this.setState(this.state.items);
        // console.log( this.state.items[i].selected);
    },
    checkAll:function () {
        this.state.globalChecked = !this.state.globalChecked;
        var ifChecked = this.state.globalChecked;
        var newItems = this.state.items.map(function(element) {
            return { start: element.start,end:element.end,hours:element.hours,selected: ifChecked };
        });
        this.setState({items:newItems});
    },
    remove : function () {
        for(var i = 0;i<this.state.items.length;i++)
        {
            if(this.state.items[i].selected)
            {
               this.state.items.splice(i,1);
                i--;
            }
        }
        this.setState(this.state.items);
    },
    render: function(){
        var arrayItems =  this.state.items.map(function (item,i) {
            return (
                <tr key={i}>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"  checked={item.selected} onClick={this.handleChecked.bind(this,i)}/></td>
                    <td><FormattedDate value={item.start}/></td>
                    <td><FormattedDate value={item.end}/></td>
                    <td>{item.hours}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button className="editButton"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        }.bind(this));

        return (
                <table className="myTable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" onClick={this.checkAll}/></th>
                    <th>Start Date:</th>
                    <th>End Date:</th>
                    <th id="hoursField">Hours:</th>
                    <th id="editField">Edit:</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {arrayItems}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                    <td colSpan="4">
                        <span className="addButtonDisplay"><Modal items={this.state.items}></Modal></span>
                        <button className="myButton" onClick={this.remove}>Remove period</button>
                        <button className="myButton">Set result from merge</button>
                    </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
        );
    }
 });

var Modal = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            items:this.props.items,
            show: false,
            startDate:null,
            endDate:null
        };
    },
    handleChangeStartDate:function (date) {
        this.setState({
            startDate:date
        });
    },
    handleChangeEndDate:function (date) {
        this.setState({
            endDate:date
        });
    },
    showModal() {
        this.setState({show: true});
    },

    hideModal() {
        this.setState({show: false});
    },
    addElement:function () {
        var workHours = this.workHours.value;
        var objectToAdd = {start:this.state.startDate,end:this.state.endDate,hours:workHours};
        this.state.items.push(objectToAdd);
        this.setState({items:this.state.items});
        this.state.startDate = null;
        this.state.endDate = null;
        this.setState({show: false});
    },
    render : function(){
        var close = () => this.setState({ show: false});
        return (
            <ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar>
                <button className="myButton" onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true})}>Add period</button>
                <ReactBootstrap.Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.hideModal} dialogClassName="custom-modal">
                    <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">Modal heading</ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>
                    </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
                       <form name="myForm">
                                <div>
                                    <span id="example">Enter Start Date: </span>
                                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.handleChangeStartDate} className="datepickerStartAlignment"/>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <span>Enter End Date: </span>
                                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.endDate} onChange={this.handleChangeEndDate} className="datepickerEndAlignment"/>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span>Enter Work Hours: </span>
                                    <input ref={(ref) => this.workHours = ref} onChange={this.state.handleChangeWorkHours} id="hoursInput" name="workHours" type="number" min="0" required/>
                                </div>
                        </form>

                    </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
                        <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.addElement}>Add</ReactBootstrap.Button>
                        <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.hideModal}>Close</ReactBootstrap.Button>
                    </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
                </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
           </ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you describe, what exactly don't helped in answer, and we will try to figure out?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you shouldn't store `items` variable in `Modal` component state.

Store it only in props, and add `onAddElement` callback, which will be provided from parent component, like this:

```
// Modal.js
var Modal = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      show: false,
      startDate:null,
      endDate:null
    };
  },

  // Other methods...

  addElement: function () {
    var workHours = this.workHours.value;
    var objectToAdd = {start:this.state.startDate,end:this.state.endDate,hours:workHours};

    // Instead of adding object to state, we are providing it to callback.
    this.props.onAddElement(objectToAdd);

    // Also, you shouldn't change existing state values, provide them to `setState` function instead.
    this.setState({
      show: false,
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    // Your render code.
  }
}
```

Next, in you parent component, you should define `handleAddElement` function and pass it to `Modal` component:

```
// DiaryTable.js
var DiaryTable = React.createClass({
  // Defining `handleAddElement` function, which will be invoked
  // everytime you add new element
  handleAddElement: function(element) {
    this.setState({
      // `concat` method returns new array with appended element.
      items: this.state.items.concat(element)
    });
  }

  render: function() {
    // I removed other markup, to made explanation more clear.
    return (
      <Modal items={this.state.items} onAddElement={this.handleAddElement.bind(this)}></Modal>
    );
  };
});
```

Hope, it helps!